# Calling python from matlab - SSL module is not available on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, bash, matlab, ubuntu, ssl

I am calling a python script from Matlab using a system call.
The script is doing a post request to a https url.
This used to work in Ubuntu 14.04 but stopped working in 16.04

You can test it like this:

pre requisites: matlab, python, python-requests

#### From bash command line:

```
$ python -c "import requests; a = requests.get( 'https://github.com');print len(a.text);"
```

- Output:

  ```
  25696
  ```

#### From matlab:

```
>> system('python -c "import requests; a = requests.get( ''https://github.com'');print len(a.text);"')
```

- Output on ubuntu 14.04:

  ```
  25706

  ans =

    0
  ```
- Output on ubuntu 16.04:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
      return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
      return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
      resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
      r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
      raise SSLError(e, request=request)
  requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.

  ans =

       1
  ```

Matlab version is R2014a in both cases.
Python version 2

I have tried to install different packages versions with no luck.I do not know what should I look for, since the problem seems to be the detection of a shared library (libssl 1.0.0) that works in one system and fails in the other. How can I debug this?

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I just ran into this also. I found that importing matlab.engine breaks python requests. The following example fails: python -c "import matlab.engine; import requests; a = requests.get( 'https://github.com');print len(a.text);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a workaround for python run from Matlab to force python to load the appropriate version of libssl.o:

```
RTLD_NOW = 2;
RTLD_DEEPBIND = 8;
flag = bitor(RTLD_NOW, RTLD_DEEPBIND); % RTLD_NOW | RTLD_DEEPBIND
py.sys.setdlopenflags(int32(flag));
py.importlib.import_module('_ssl');
```

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/297090-when-i-run-a-python-module-which-imports-ssl-py-error-occurs-but-it-s-ok-to-run-the-straight-pyt?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Thanks! I can not test this at the moment but the provided link looks exactly like my problem, so I'm accepting this answer